# Firestore Thread 1: Fatal error when loading data to tableview using real time listener (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a financial management app and need to display all the transactions in a tableview. The app was working fine until I updated the Pod (I hadn't touched this project since last Christmas, just came back to it). So, now I'm facing this 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.'

I have tried modifying my 'struct' but it didn't help.

This is the function in my tableview:

```
func checkUpdates() {
    reference(to: .transactions).whereField("timeStamp", isGreaterThan: Date()).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach {
            diff in
            if diff.type == .added {
                self.transactionArray.append(transactionStruct(dictionary: diff.document.data())!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get Thread 1 error message at line 7 where it says "self.transactionArray.append..."

These below are for the struct:

```
protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String: Any])
}

struct transactionStruct {
    var description: String
    var amount: Int
    var timeStamp: Date
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return ["description": description,
                "amount": amount,
                "timeStamp": timeStamp]
    }
}

extension transactionStruct: DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let amount = dictionary["amount"] as? Int,
            let description = dictionary["description"] as? String,
            let timeStamp = dictionary["timeStamp"] as? Date else { return nil }

        self.init(description: description, amount: amount, timeStamp: timeStamp)
    }
}
```

Now after I add a new entry, the app will crash and I get this Thread 1: Fatal error every time. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Any exclamation mark is a candidate to crash the app.**

The initializer in the `TransactionStruct`extension – please name structs with starting capital letter – is failable so use optional binding for safe unwrapping

```
if diff.type == .added, let transaction = TransactionStruct(dictionary: diff.document.data()) {
    self.transactionArray.append(transaction)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If nothing happens then the passed dictionary has changed.